# Not able to create MYSQL table due to autoincrement duplicate

Tags: mysql, database

Below is my table schema.

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_certificate`
(
`certificate_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,    
`certificate_number` varchar(150) NOT NULL,    
`vin_no_id` varchar(50) NOT NULL,    
`product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,    
`duration_id` int(11) NOT NULL,    
`clientId` varchar(30) NOT NULL,    
`first_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,    
`last_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,    
`state` varchar(256) NOT NULL,    
`city` varchar(256) NOT NULL,    
`mobile` varchar(30) NOT NULL,    
`alternate_contact_number` varchar(30) NOT NULL,    
`land_line` varchar(256) NOT NULL,    
`address` varchar(300) NOT NULL,    
`email_id` varchar(50) NOT NULL,    
`registration_no` varchar(20) NOT NULL,    
`make_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,    
`model_id` varchar(100) NOT NULL,    
`vehical_sale_date` date NOT NULL,    
`vehical_delivery_date` date NOT NULL,    
`engine_number` varchar(30) NOT NULL,    
`fuel` varchar(20) NOT NULL,    
`odometer_reading` varchar(30) NOT NULL,    
`color` varchar(32) NOT NULL,    
`variant` varchar(16) NOT NULL,    
`refered_by` int(11) NOT NULL,    
`user_id` varchar(30) NOT NULL,    
`created_date` date NOT NULL,    
`complete_status` varchar(30) NOT NULL,    
`price_amt` varchar(20) NOT NULL,    
`servicetax_amt` varchar(20) NOT NULL,    
`total_amt` varchar(20) NOT NULL,    
`quotationNumber` bigint(20) NOT NULL,    
`programstart` date NOT NULL,    
`programend` date NOT NULL,    
`uploaded_certificate` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT '0-No,1-Yes',    
`certificate_create_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,    
`savedCertificateDate` datetime NOT NULL,    
`purchaseCertificateDate` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',    
`transaction_no` varchar(256) NOT NULL,    
`expired` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'  
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

It throws an error like

Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key

I am not getting what's issue, there is only one auto increment field name 'certificate_id'.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You must include the `PRIMARY KEY` constraint in your DDL for an `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_certificate`
(
    `certificate_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    ...
)
```

To be clear, `AUTO_INCREMENT` is basically just an attribute for indexed keys. It does not define an attribute as an index in the schema. So a column may be an indexed key without an `AUTO_INCREMENT` attribute, but it cannot have an `AUTO_INCREMENT` attribute if it is not indexed. See the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html) for more details.

Comment: Thanks it worked. but AUTO_INCREMENT itself primary key in mysql isn't it?

Comment: auto increment column must be indexed, but this does not necessarily mean that it has to part of the PK (although it usually is the pk or part of the pk).

Comment: @Pratik no, it is not. As I noted in the above comment and in my answer, the auto increment field must be indexed.

Comment: @sherif : How to check column is indexed or not?

Comment: @Pratik by reading your DDL? The fact that you didn't specify `UNIQUE KEY` or `KEY` or `PRIMARY KEY` lets you know that the column isn't indexed. If you're asking how to determine that after the fact you can look at your `EXPLAIN table_name` from MySQL command prompt.

Comment: @Sherif Thanks for explanation, helped alot.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is very clear in this case: auto increment column must be indexed. `certificate_id` field in your table definition is not part of an index.

Comment: i didn't got that, can you give me reference.

Comment: @Shadow I think Pratik is asking for a link or reference to some more information about the auto increment business you're talking about. FYI I stumbled upon this answer while reviewing the Low Quality Posts-bin. Probably because of the short length of the answer.